# How to show AdMob banner in inappbrowser using Cordova/Ionic

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm using `ionic-framework`. I can create an `admob`banner, but when I load `inappbrowser` the banner is not shown until I close the `inappbroswer`.

Is there a way to show the AdMob banner when `inappbrowser` is open?

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you to use this plugin which I'm maintaining. You can see detailed examples on how to initiate admob when cordova is loaded: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['admobModule']);

app.config(['admobSvcProvider', function (admobSvcProvider) {
  // Optionally you can configure the options here:
  admobSvcProvider.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID"
  });
}]);


app.run(['admobSvc', function (admobSvc) {
  $rootScope.$on('admob:' + admobSvc.events.onAdOpened, function onAdOpened(evt, e) {
    console.log('adOpened: type of ad:' + e.adType);
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Have you checked it with inappbrowser? Is the banner shown when inappbrowser is opned?

Comment: @crazybob hmm... I see now, have you checked that inappbrowser is maybe covering the whole screen? I've been taking a look at the android code (lines 529 to 715 of inappbrowser.java) and it seems that it loads a new activity (InAppBrowserDialog). My suggestion would be to edit the plugin to stretch the dialog, but I'm quite sure it will be adifficult job, even if you achieve to modify it...

Comment: @crazybob an easy test you could do also is to destroy banners before opening inappbrowser, open inappbrowser and try to show banners again. Have to say that I'm very sceptict on if this is going to work, as admob is getting cordova's main view.

Comment: @Miquel Can you plesae let me know if there is anything for Ionic native PUSH plugin

Comment: @SiddaramH is that one what you are looking for? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push But don't really understand how it is related to this question...

Comment: @Miquel I'm looking for a solution to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920545/showing-admob-banner-in-inappbrowserionic